# Authentication and/or HTTPS with Plack/PSGI/Poet application

Tags: perl, plack, psgi, poet

I need to build a simple web-application. I decided to do it with [Poet](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Poet-0.13/lib/Poet.pm) ([Mason2](http://search.cpan.org/~jswartz/Mason-2.20/lib/Mason.pm)), which uses Plack.

The application should be allowed to use only by authenticated users, so I need build some login/password functionality.

There already is a Plack module [Plack::Middleware::Auth::Basic](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Plack-1.0028/lib/Plack/Middleware/Auth/Basic.pm) that allows using Basic user auth that makes it possible to setup to check `.htpasswd` or similar. But the basic authentication is not very secure; anybody can grab the login password with packet capturing or the like.

Here are 2 possible solutions:

- running my app.psgi via HTTPS(443) - link level encryption
- or is there some better auth method that allow secure auth without https?

The questions:

- Regarding HTTPS - I have no idea how to run my `app.psgi` via HTTPS. Do I need to modify my application somewhat? Any link what shows me how to run `plackup` over the https?
- or for the second: is there some method (middleware/or perl module) what allows me build  *secure* authentication over the standard unencrypted port?(80)

So, what is an relative easy way to achieve secure authentication with a Plack application?

PS: I don't care about the rest of communication. I only need secure auth that doesn't allow to grab the passwords.

PPS: https is easy with apache (and self-signed) certificate. But I have no idea how to do it with `plackup` (and or any other Plack based server)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another more simple option is to use what's built into plackup, Starman, and Thrall:

```
plackup --enable-ssl --ssl-key-file=... --ssl-cert-file=...
```

(or)

```
starman --enable-ssl --ssl-key=... --ssl-cert=...
```

(or)

```
thrall --enable-ssl --ssl-key-file=... --ssl-cert-file=...
```

Answer (score 4):

You could run your application behind some webserver like Apache that knows how to safely authenticate users.

To do this, you have two options:

1. Use FastCGI
2. Proxy requests to your app.

To go the FastCGI route, use `plackup` like this:

```
plackup -s FCGI  myapp.psgi
```

And in your Apache config, use something like this:

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module libexec/mod_fastcgi.so
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    FastCgiExternalServer /tmp/myapp.fcgi -host localhost:5000
    Alias /myapp/    /tmp/myapp.fcgi/
</IfModule>
```

Alternatively, you can make Apache proxy requests to your app:

```
ProxyPass /myapp    http://localhost:5000/
```

Since `plackup` is not recommended for production systems, you should look into [`Starman`](https://metacpan.org/module/Starman), which will limit your options to the proxy solution.

Answer (score 3):

The Apache config looks like this, if you go with Plack+Apache/mod_perl

```
<Location /path/myapp>
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlResponseHandler Plack::Handler::Apache2
  PerlSetVar psgi_app /path/to/my.psgi
</Location>
```